# Alternate methods to reload HTML table periodically

Tags: javascript, php, refresh

I have a webpage that includes two tables, a chart and some text, each of which are to update periodically without the usual HTML refresh "flicker."  My (working) example includes the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Active chats</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
           var auto_refresh = setInterval(
              function ()
              {
                 $('#concurrentChart').load('myscript?update=graph').fadeIn("slow") ;
                 $('#chats').load('myscript?update=chat').fadeIn('slow') ;
                 $('#watchers').load('myscript?update=watchers').fadeIn('slow') ;
                 $('#currentTime').load('myscript?update=time').fadeIn('slow') ;
              }, 10000); // refresh every 10 seconds
    </script>

    <style>
            ...
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    ...
    <div id='concurrentChart'> ... </div>
    <div id='chats'> ... </div>
    <div id='watchers'> ... </div>
    <div id='currentTime'> ... </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

... and PHP code to interpret the refresh request...

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    ....
    if (array_key_exists('query', $urlParts)) {
        $query = $urlParts['query'] ;
        if (preg_match('/^update=(graph|watchers|chat|time)$/', $query, $matches)) {
            $updateWhat = $matches[1] ;
            $dbCriteria = [ 'minimumEpoch' => $_SESSION['minimumEpoch']
                           , 'livestreamId' => null
                                    ] ;
            switch($updateWhat) {
                case 'graph': 
                    echo latestChatViewerCountGraph() ;
                    break ;
                case 'watchers': 
                    echo latestChatsGetWatchersHTML( $dbCriteria ) ;
                    break ;
                case 'chat': 
                    echo latestChatsGetChatTable($dbCriteria) ;
                    break ;
                case 'time':
                    echo latestChatCurrentTimeImage($ChrisTime) ;
                    break ;
            } // switch
            exit() ;
        } // $query is update=something
    } // $url exists in array
} // GET request
```

As I indicated, the page works, but one issue is that each of the DIVs has to be updated on every "cycle," even if the data hasn't changed (since I have unconditional $(#section).load(...)

It occurs to me that it would be better to make that reload conditional but I don't know enough javascript to know how to accomplish this (not to mention the interplay between PHP and javascript messes with my head!).  I know efficient methods to determine if the data changed.  I'm looking for an efficient approach to the actual refresh that will meet the need.

Ideally, each of the functions (latestChatsGetWatchersHTML for example) would actually do the table updates, but only if the data has changed.

So I'm thinking that the refresh would need to look more like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var auto_refresh = setInterval(
       function () {
           call_url('myscript?update=graph') ;
           call_url('myscript?update=chat')
           call_url('myscript?update=watchers')
           call_url'myscript?update=time')
              }, 10000); // refresh every 10 seconds
    </script>
```

But I'm not sure what to replace "call_url" with (AJAX probably - but that's another learning curve), and then each of those rebuild functions would have to update their respective DIV and I'm not sure how to make that happen...

I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me, but rather for technical details for an approach that might fit the bill.

Comment: First, `$(...).load()` **is** AJAX.  On each refresh cycle, your code is making **four** HTTP requests back to the server. The first thing to do would be to combine all those server request so that one refresh could return a single data structure with all the content for the page. As for checking changes, that probably has to be done on the server, and the details have to do with the exact nature of your application.

Comment: Thanks, @Pointy.  Yeah, I know how to ensure the data changes, nit an issue there.  I'll update the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

How about a **timestamp** that indicates when the last change was made?  The AJAX call would send that; if the response is empty, then don't bother repainting the page.  You could maybe even shrink the 10-second interval.

Furthermore, ask for updates to all 4 in a single request.  There would be a single `myscript?update=all4,ts1,ts2,ts3,ts4`.  Perhaps the return should be a **4-element JSON** associative array with whichever (if any) of the 4 thingies have changed since the timestamp mentioned.  Then fade-in each thingie that shows up in the JSON.  (That is, 4 IF statements in place of the for `.load`.)

A **user ecperience caution**...  When one area is updated, will that move the stuff below it up or down (on the screen)?  If so, will this lead to a poor user experience because of things jumping around while the user is reading them and/or reaching for something (eg, a URL link) with the mouse and accidentally landing on the wrong spot?

Comment: Thanks, @Rick James.  This is all very good, except the time doesn't really help me in this case.  The data loaded to each table is timestamped, but its appearance in the database may be wildly delayed due to commitment control and the like.  The experience caution I much appreciate; the divs are all laid out such that dynamic sizing is consistent to the platform (browser/device) and not dependent upon the data.  I really like the idea of requesting all four at once, but do not know how to separate the AJAX responses to know what belongs where.  Is there a guide for that?

Comment: @Dennis if the AJAX requests can all go to the same server, then send 4 timestamps; compare to db; build ajax response with only the ones with newer timestamps in the db.  (Or maybe I am not understanding how the timestamps need to work.)

Comment: I added a bit to my Answer.

Comment: Say for one of the refreshes we want to list open orders, and the list needs to be updated when a new order comes in.  Say further that the new order has a timestamp, established at the beginning of the order process, which may have been 5 minutes ago (or more or less).  That timestamp would not be helpful here.  But perhaps something similar (order number for example) may be used.  Have to think about that one since order number likewise was established early in the process.

Comment: @Dennis - Something like: The requester keeps the timestamp of last update was checked for; the server has the timestamp of the latest order came in.  The server compares them to decide whether to send data.  And, yes, an 'order number' would also work.